# Upgrading T410 w/Perc 6i to Windows Server 2022

Tags: dell-poweredge, dell-perc

I have a PowerEdge T410 with a Perc 6/i configured with a Raid5 array.
It is running Windows Server 2019 Datacenter and hosts several Hiper-V vms. Due to contractual obligations, we need to upgrade to Windows Server 2022. When I try to do the upgrade (in-place), it fails flagging the perc driver as unsupported (megasas.sys 6.706.00). Unsurprisingly, there is not an updated driver.

My question - Can I replace the Perc Adapter with a newer one?

I really don't want to replace the server unless I have to.

Eric.

Answer (score 2):

Obligatory legal note: I work for Dell.

If you're asking can you replace it with a newer perc and it be in a supported config? Definitely not. None of the PERCs that were qualified for the T410 have been made for the better part of a decade.

Could you hack one on... maybe??? I would honestly be more inclined to just buy a cheap generic RAID controller and use that instead of a Dell PERC. It's more likely to simultaneously play nicely with the server and Windows imo.

That said, you can tell from my other posts that I'm all for hacking stuff together, but a T410? That thing was released in 2009. Glad it's still running for you but at this point you may as well buy a cheap laptop and run it as a server. It would be faster . (But seriously - it almost certainly would.)

Comment: Thanks, that is what I was figuring. My boss asked me if it was possible. My concern with using a generic card is the "wiring harness" on the 410. In a quick search I haven't seen a card with similar connectors. I'll have to do a more thorough search before making a recommendation. (Dell servers being so reliable can be problematic at times :-) )

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this question is still actual, but according to Dell documentation, T410 supports PERC H700 [Poweredge T410 Specs](https://i.dell.com/sites/csdocuments/Shared-Content_data-Sheets_Documents/en/T410-SpecSheet.pdf). Windows Server 2022 has built-in drivers for Poweredge Gen10 RAID controllers. You can try replacing PERC 6/i with PERC H700. It should recognize hard drives and give you an option to import RAID configuration at first boot.

[Windows Server 2022 support by Dell servers](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000191294/windows-server-2022-driver-support-for-dell-emc-poweredge-servers)